# Conditional function in PHP to populate a table with images

Tags: php, html, sql

I have the following table in HTML with the result in the right hand side populated by querying a SQL database.

[image: Table]

The code for populating each cell is as follows:

```
  <tr>
    <td>House</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_buyerdetails['tod_house']; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

What I want is instead of the result from the database being entered (in this case the values are just 1 for yes and 0 for no) is a conditional statement in the PHP so that if the result is yes, an image of a tick is shown and likewise a cross for no. Ive tried doing the following:

```
<?php 
if ($row_buyerdetails['tod_house'] == "0") {
   echo "no it isnt!";}
else{
   echo "yes it is!";} ?>
```

This works fine, but i dont know how to call an image in php.

Also as there will eventually be 30 or so identical `if` functions in the table, is there any way I can set a function up which retrieves the data from the table, analyses it, and is able to send the image to the correct cell in the table for each query?

---

Tried with no avail to add a function as suggest by the two answers below... my function is:

```
<script>
function rowimage($item){

if ($item == "0"){
    return (<img src ="images/no.png"/>);   
}
else{
    return (<img src = "images/yes.png/>);
}}
</script>
```

and my call to the function is:

```
  <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td><?php echo rowimage($row_buyerdetails['phone_number'])?></td>
  </tr>
```

But I get the error:

[image: error]

Im pretty sure there is an easy solution to this but im only in the very first throws of learning Javascript and so troubleshooting is not my forte at the moment!

Comment: You need to change `return (<img src ="images/no.png"/>);` to `return ('<img src ="images/no.png"/>');` Note the addition of the single quotes around the entire return string

Comment: Also, did you define the function in the same php file as where you are printing the results?

Comment: @mituw16 Yes the function is in the head of the same .php file, the table is in the body, Ive altered the return as suggested but still getting the same error message!

Comment: I see you have the php function inside of a js script tag. Try moving the php function to be inside of a php block like `<?php function rowimage($item) { //code } ?>`

Comment: Genius! sorted it, thankyou @mituw16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can reduce this down using a ternary operator:

```
<?php echo (!$row_buyerdetails['tod_house']) ? 'no it isnt!' : 'yes it is!' ?>
```

You don't 'call an image' in PHP, but rather you can generate a HTML tag for it. Let's assume that your image is located in the root directory, and is called `yes.png` and `no.png`. You could easily create a function to output the `<img />` tag according to the DB value as follows:

```
function prettifyRow($fieldName)
{
    $html = '<img src="images/';
    $html.= (!$fieldName) ? 'no' : 'yes';
    $html.= '.png" />';
    echo $html;
}
```

Now, you can easily call this function in your HTML template and pass in the field value as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td>House</td>
    <td><?php prettifyRow($row_buyerdetails['tod_house']) ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: please see my addition to the original question!

Comment: Looks like you didn't follow my answer. You have typos. Please use my edited answer, in its original form (i.e. don't modify it).

Comment: I get a syntax error on the "$html.= (!$field) ? 'no' : 'yes'" line?

Comment: Sorry, try the edited version. I missed a semicolon.

Comment: still got a syntax error! I dont understand what that line is doing so I cant troubleshoot it on my own!

Comment: Put the whole thing in PHP blocks and its working. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Great. For reference, the line you didn't understand is a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to analyze it. I would so something like the following.

```
function analyze($item) {
    return ($item == "0" ? "no it isn't!" : "<img src='urltopicture' />");
}
```

Then in the html you would put something like

```
 <td><?php echo analyze($row["tod_house"]);?></td>
```

Comment: please see my addition to the original question!